# Typescript and promises

Tags: typescript

I am just getting up to speed with typescript 1.5 and promises (currently using es6-promise from Jake Archibald):
    A few classes, one class instantiates the details class, which instantiates the common class, but I need the common class to complete before the details class can make its call. From what I understand, promises is the key to make this happen.... but struggling on how to get promises into the class and not just the class methods. Trying to avoid jQuery promises since, from what I have read, they do not follow promises/a+ exactly...

```
some pseudo-code:

export class UserData extends Promise<UserData> (?){
 _cd = new CommonData();
 *another ajax call, based on data returned obtained commondata call*

}
export class CommonData {  
 private _instance = this;  
 public Name: string= null;
 constructor () {
    *I want to make my class promisable, not just the methods*
     new promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
         ??
     });
  }
  getData() {
    var parentClass = this._instance;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       $.ajax({
               success: {
                  ...
                  parentClass.Name = *data from ajax*;
                  resolve();
               },
               error: {
                  reject();
               }
       }
  }
}
export class UI { 
   var us = new UserDetails();
}
```

Comment: Generally you don't have classes that implement a promise (I'm sure there are exceptions to this rule).  Most of the time you see the value of the promise passed around, contains the class.  `new Promise(function(resolve) { resolve(new UserData); })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If UserData is initialized asynchronously, then create a factory method that returns a Promise. In this case `initUserData` is the factory method and the underlying constructor should not be used externally, although in TypeScript it can't be made private.

In general, as a guide for reactive programming, if you decide to program with Promises, expect to expose a `Promise<T>` wherever a synchronously coded program would expose a `T`. Not always true, sometimes you have have to block to resolve, but every such instance of blocking has a slight code smell that needs examination.

```
export class UserData {
    constructor(commonData: CommonData) {
        // Construct your UserData
    } 

    initUserData(): Promise<UserData> {
        Promise<CommonData> common = getCommonDataPromise();
        return common.then(c => new UserData(c));
    }
}
```

Comment: Both basarat and masonk answers were helpful for different reasons; basarat give the overview of the pattern I needed and masonk went into a bit more detail.

Answer (score 3):

> class UserData extends Promise (?){

No. Instead think composition: (not inheritance .. unless *you are writing a new  promise library ... which is not the case here*)

```
class UserData {
   public data; 

   constructor(){
       doStuff().then(()=>this.data = new SomeData());
   } 
}
```